# Regarding the author's right to edit his own question

Tags: discussion

> [How do I add minutes to a time data type?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31669/how-do-i-add-minutes-to-a-time-data-type#question)

This question has spontaneously devolved into an edit war. The author feels slighted. Here is his "closing volley" and then my ruling as a moderator (hey, I'm just cleaning up stuff).

> **Final notes:**
>   It is my right, as the person who asked the question, to determine if the the question has been answered in a satisfactory way. At this time I do not feel that there is an answer which fully answers the question I am trying to ask.

There is a lot of other information, which can be seen in the history link on the Q, but I'm here to settle the dispute over content, not the technical accuracy of the answer. So, if you're ***ALL*** with me and understand that that is the **POINT** of this post, then we shall begin.

---

It is indeed the author's right to determine accuracy. However, as the author, you don't get to retroactively say "oh, you absolutely didn't read my mind and answer what I needed." To wit: Trisped should have considered this portion:

> **Update:**
>   A correct answer should contain the following information:
>
> - How to add minutes to to a time data type.
> - That the proposed solution does not result in a loss of precision.
> - Issues or concerns to be aware of in the event that the minutes would be to too large to fit in a time variable, or risk of rolling the time variable over. If there are no issues then please state so.

When he asked the question. Now, that being said, that's a little insensitive of me to say, because sometimes we have to ask the question and have some discussion over what makes it a great question. I don't see any such back and forth, but we can chalk it up to "I re-read the question and this seems to be missing". That's fair. Given the new requirements (which I have a technical answer on, but which this forum is not for technical accuracy but for the running of the site, it being *meta*, let's keep it to the asking of questions and giving of answers) the answer still seemed valid. So what's up with the rant?

The rant says "Oh, Aaron changed two of my "record" to "row", woe is me". Yes Trisped, I am using sarcasm to make light of the rant. The issue is that apps use records, database tables store records as *rows*. When discussing query, the technical term is *row*. You don't get to change that. What you display on screen is a *record*. Learn the differences in terminology, because your entire programming career will be filled with this sort of nuance. He also removed a comment which was superfluous and didn't add to the conversation, as I've never had rowcount interrupt my query results before. To be honest, I forget how much value it even is anymore. But the point being, when someone with Aaron's expertise removes a comment from a query that he sees as superfluous to the discussion of answering your question, that's not something to get pissy on.

So Trisped, consider your hand smacked at this point, for the following:

- Starting an edit war with a moderator (Jack Douglas) who reverted your edit and asked you to not do that,
- Arguing with people who are trying to tell you what the proper operation of the requested function are,
- Being highly pedantic about the edits of your question without working to engage better clarification of the question.

And with all that said, I feel like if you stay with the network (this sort of thing is the reason people leave the network, but that's a shame) then I think you'll make a great going-forward user of our network. You obviously want to know this stuff, and that's highly important. Don't give up on us yet, just learn that others can edit your stuff *and that that's ok!* That's all you have to do to earn my blessing, and this whole thing just goes away.

---

Aaron Bertrand:

You get your hand publicly slapped for deleting your great answer, and for arguing when this should've become a moderation issue, and for your pissy comments (like I haven't left literally dozens of those, so I know I'm absolutely not pure in this case, but I still get my hand smacked, and often).

Thank you for not continuing an edit war, and for being mostly calm.

---

To everyone else:

Thank you for not getting into an edit war, and for not destroying the basic thread of what's going on here.

---

## What happens now:

If there are actual merits of answering this question to be discussed that aren't technical solutions, then now is the time for Trisped to respond with an answer. He can even rant and rave here, if he likes, because that's what this post is about. However, that will NOT bleed over to the main DBA.SE, this has become a site-operation issue, and not a post editing issue.

Comment: FWIW the way DATEADD works with TIME is that it simply rolls over at midnight, and over and over again, so DATEADD(MINUTE, 1000000, @sometime) is equivalent to DATEADD(MINUTE, 1000000 % 1440, @sometime) - at least in SQLFiddle with SQL Server 2012

Comment: So you use a DateTime, because then you can detect day rollover, and you just extract the time, but these are all technical discussions :p

Comment: @jcolebrand his point is that if you only care about the time, you don't need to use datetime.

Comment: bah, anytime you add even a second to a time, you have to monitor date. Anybody who understands time addition has to see that. `23:59:59` + `00:00:02` => ???

Comment: @jcolebrand I may be wrong but I never saw anything about how he actually wanted rollover to be handled.  The BIG problem is when only the end time rolls over and not the begin time.  Then you can't get the interval with DATEDIFF without reversing the order AND subtracting from the number of units in the day.

Comment: @CadeRoux which becomes "question clarification" which should've happened in the first place. We learn, we move on. We're doing that here.

Comment: I did talk about that in one of the comment streams that has since been purged.

Answer (score 9):

Trisped seemed to get angry for a number of reasons:

- I changed two instances of `record` to `row`, but overlooked a third. I did this only as an addendum to two other edits (removing the comment, but I removed it not for the reason you suggest, but rather because it coerced horizontal scrollbars on the code sample) and the addition of the word `that` to make one of the sentences more coherent. I don't think the outcome would have been any different if I had caught all three instances of the term, since that was a substantial part of his complaint on multiple occasions, but who knows? The reason I changed that word is because, as you suggest, the widely observed correct term for a "record" at rest is a row. Record makes me cringe unless we're talking about vinyl or Access (well, I still cringe there too).
- I suggested an approach that he had allegedly discarded before asking the question, because (again allegedly) he didn't think it would work. He failed to include that information in the original question, but made a big stink about it afterward - to the point of demanding that I add some context to the answer around the fact that `DATEADD` and `TIME` play nice, holding his accept as hostage until I do so.
- He had some kind of hangup about potential loss of precision, and demanded that be included in my answer as well, even though it was not disclosed as a concern in the question. For this he could have simply tried the code that I provided and determined that there would be no loss of precision.

Ultimately, he got his answer, so I'm not sure why he got so uppity and downright unappreciative about it.

But I still feel like the question should be closed and discarded. Again, Trisped got his answer, and the question is unlikely to help many future visitors that will have the same misconception about (or lack of willingness to try) `DATEADD` before posting.

Comment: I agree that it's unlikely to help anyone in the future, as the MSDN right thing to do is DATEADD.

Comment: The reason I changed your edit back was because you said I could, because of the inconsistency, and because every definition I could find indicated that the correct term was "record".

Comment: I do not remember saying that I would not edit my question as you requested.  I do remember saying that if you added the part about return type I would accept it and I do remember you indicating that I would have to edit my question first.  Right after that everything was side tracked by your quote from Celko.  I was under the impression that we were negotiating, not making demands.

Comment: @Trisped And I tried to explain that what you found and what most industry experts tend to agree on are two different things. <shrug> If your main problem was the inconsistency (as I said, I overlooked one instance of `record`), we could have just as easily changed the third instance to `row`. It does not look good for you to get into an edit war with a high-rep user *and* a moderator.

Comment: As I indicated in my question this morning, if you have an official source for "what most industry experts tend to agree" then I would be pleased to have it.

Comment: @Trisped how many people need to tell you that a record and a row are not the same concept, even if they are confused / deemed interchangeable by a large portion of the industry? Your question still says record. Like I said before, if you want to keep using the wrong term, GO AHEAD. Nobody is trying to edit your question again.

Comment: @Trisped the change is accurate. I still question what this has to do with `DATETIME`, `TIME`, and `DATEADD` precision.

Comment: I am a bit confused on your comments.  How should I interpret "And I tried to explain that what you found and what most industry experts tend to agree on are two different things." with "... a record and a row are not the same concept, even if they are confused / deemed interchangeable by a large portion of the industry?" and the fact that I believe that I was talking about a record, not a row (I know they are not the same)?

Comment: Having said that, here's a citation: Itzik Ben-Gan, et al., *Querying Microsoft SQL Server* (Sebastopol: O'Reily, 2012), pp. 10-11. 

The relevant section starts with "Your use of terminology reflects on your knowledge."

Comment: @swasheck Thank you, but as I indicated the source needs to be from an ofical source.

Comment: @Trisped it's your world and we're just playing in it. What would you consider "official?"

Comment: @Trisped "needs to be", and then what? I'm not sure how I can convince you that Itzik and Celko have stated as much but you choose to ignore it. Do you expect Microsoft to have official documentation that states that thou shalt call it a row and never a record? Good luck. Half the people there are the problem.

Comment: @Trisped I'm not sure what purpose your continued badgering serves. You got to keep your question with the word "record" instead of "row," how else do you want this situation to be rectified?

Comment: @swasheck As stated in the question before the last edit, an official source would be one of the standards, or (since we are discussing a Microsoft implementation) the Microsoft documentation.

Comment: @Trisped so a Microsoft-licensed publication is, or is not, "official?"

Comment: @Trisped to what end? What is your end game? Maybe you should answer this question with an official Microsoft source that states that it is always a record and should never be called a row: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31805/what-is-the-difference-between-a-record-and-a-row

Comment: @swasheck I suspect he wants something on the Interwebs, none of this fancy printed book stuff.

Comment: @swasheck A licensed publication is not official.  A licensed publication is allowed to present the authors personal preference and suggestions.

Comment: Web based would be better, yes.

Comment: @Trisped until you can explain to me WHY anyone should do this for you, your badgering is going to continue to be ignored.

Comment: End game: You said I am wrong.  You might be right, but I need proof before I change.  In the interest of the community I will post my previous counter to it.  You should know though that similar questions have already been asked (with accepted answers).

Comment: @Trisped you could always just NOT CHANGE, and continue to call it a record. It's not like you would be alone. My goal in the edit was to gently coerce some conformance but, it has been long clear that that was not appreciated. <shrug> Just keep calling it a record; your requirements are way too particular for me.

Comment: @Trisped – When the designers/developers at Microsoft (or even Sybase) once upon a time decided to name a variable to check the number of "things" returned by a query they used [@@rowcount](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx). And when they wanted a property to figure out how many "things" there are in a recordset they choose [RecordCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676701(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Hi Mikael, your comment on Aaron's answer was very helpful.  The point which has been lost is that we are not talking about things stored in a table.  I agree, records stored in a SQL table (or any time they are stored in a row like fashion) should be called a row, to further disambiguate the thing being discussed.  I also agree that select queries return rows, insert commands create rows, update commands modify rows, and delete commands remove rows.

Comment: @Trisped false. the point which has been lost is that *your original question has to do with adding time to a `time` data type.* You then undertook this quest for some authoritative documentation for many, many things (overflowing a `time`). You got your feelings hurt when Aaron edited your question so then you started tilting at those windmills. Let's not lose scope of what has actually occurred.

Comment: @Trisped you're all over the place. Here you say: `we are not talking about things stored in a table` and `insert commands create rows` - except your question says (and this is one of the instances I had originally corrected): `inserts two records into a table`. <facepalm>

Comment: To answer the question of "who says it's called a row", I refer everyone to any MSDN reference of "ROW_NUMBER" or "ROWVERSION" or the fact that a DataTable, which is a C# direct extraction representation of a table from TSQL, calls it `DataTable.Rows`.

Comment: @Trisped Ok, hmm.. English is only my fourth language right after TSQL, Delphi and Swedish but you did write "inserts two records into a table" and that would make them rows right? or?

Comment: **ENOUGH WITH THE DISCUSSION OF ROWS VS RECORDS.**

Comment: Gentlemen, shake hands and let's agree to move on. Let's focus on the mechanical aspects of adding time to a time and answer the originally asked question

Comment: @swasheck First, Aaron said I could revert the change (which I questioned because it did not make sense to me).  Mikael's attempt to resolve my issue was valid, but miss directed.  In an attempt to get an answer to the issue of what is a row and what is not, I attempted to clarify the issue we were discussing.

Comment: @jcolebrand that's already been done. Might I remind you that *you* indirectly invited this discussion. Trisped keeps pushing for official proof that he is wrong.

Comment: @Trisped the _clarification of questions_ occurs in the _comments_. Not in edits.

Comment: @AaronBertrand and it has been provided. He can dispute that we have provided proof, but we have. We even have a standing SE Q to answer the fact. Since it has an official question, there is no compelling reason to have it become a comment debate on meta.

Comment: @jcolebrand: I would partly challenge that assertion: `clarification of questions occurs in the comments. Not in edits.` All relevant information should to into the question, *not* into comments. But you shouldn't *change* the question to something else, especially after answers have been given. I quote the FAQ: `If other users ask you for more information in the comments, edit your question using the edit link just below your original question.`

Comment: @Erwin for clarification, in this case, some information about the OP's understanding came to light in the comments. He then demanded that the answer reflect the clarifications that were made in the comments, but when asked, refused to update the question to match because he felt his misunderstanding was implied. <shrug> Damned if you do, damned if you don't.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter you don't ask for clarification by editing the question. You provide clarification by editing the question. Make sure we read the same page, ok? Once clarification has been reached, _then_ an edit is made. In this case that is not what occurred. Not by my reading as an outside third-party observer coming in when a situation had escalated.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I didn't want to comment on the case that sparked this discussion. Felt like that already got all the attention it needed. I'm trying work on the consensus how to deal with question edits generally. I keep advertising to put all relevant information into the *question*, since it's clearer for the general public. Ask and discuss what's missing in comments, don't hide essential information there. jcolebrand's comment seemed to go into another direction.

Comment: @jcolebrand: I quoted the part that put me off. `clarification of questions occurs in the comments`. You last comment helps to disambiguate and sounds right to me.

Comment: Not to resurrect a dead thread, but I think I understand what Trisped is trying to say.  His comment states that inserting to a table creates rows, but the object that you are inserting the data from is a record, which seems consistent with the answer that jcolebrand posted to the question that Aaron asked about this.  It follows, then that this argument is about whether the subject is the object that data is being inserted from, or the object in the table after the insert, which is a much worse argument than defining row vs record. imho.